# With the state_machine gem, can I can I perform a transition without saving?

Tags: ruby

I'm working on an app that uses [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine). I want to call a transition method but **not** persist the change, so that I have an opportunity to check whether the proposed change is authorized. Eg:

```
def some_controller_action
  # ...
  account.close     # but don't save...
  authorize account # will explode if current_user may not do this
  if account.save ....
```

How can I do this?

Comment: As of now, `state_machine` looks abandoned and I wouldn't choose it for a new project, but I needed to solve this problem today.

Answer (score 1):

### Pass `false`

Eg:

```
account.close(false) # does not save
```

This isn't exactly documented, but I [found it here](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/issues/13#issuecomment-1744855).

Comment: Wow, that was a quick turn-around. :D

Comment: @CheeseFry Yep, I came here to document something I learned in searchable format. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/